# Cannot Display Empty Priority In Custom Agenda View After 9.1 Upgrade

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, upgrade

I like using [org agenda column view](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-column-view.html) to view my important TODO items. To make that happen I use the following code:

```
(setq org-agenda-overriding-columns-format
      "%TODO %4PRIORITY(Pri.) %50ITEM(Task) %3POM_Estimate(Est.) %6POM_Pomodori(Poms) %6POM_Interruptions(Ints) %TAGS %16CLOCKSUM_T(Today's Clocksum)")
(setq org-agenda-view-columns-initially t)
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("." "Simple agenda view"
         ((tags "+today" ((org-agenda-span 'day)))
          (agenda "")))))
```

As you can see, the second column of my "agenda table" is the TODO's priority. I like to change these priorities a lot, and often I'll remove the priority entirely.

The problem is that after upgrading from 8.2 to 9.1 all of my TODO's with empty priorities appear to have a priority of "B". Also, when I try to remove the priority in the agenda view I get this message:

```
user-error: No priority cookie found in line
```

This of course makes sense because when I leave the agenda view the TODO isn't marked with a priority. It just looks like the priority is `B` in the agenda view.

This is especially confusing to me because it used to work with Org 8.2. Has anyone else seen anything like this?

Comment: Emacs 25 ships with org-version 8.2.10.  Everyone and their mother are using org-version 9.something.  Why are you using 8.3 and are you sure that is the right number?  [And, of course, Emacs 26 will be released soon with org-version 9.something.]

Comment: I tried upgrading from 8.2.x to 9.x but I got a ton of errors. Apparently a bunch of my config settings are no long supported and are breaking in weird, difficult-to-debug ways. Also, I noticed that there were a LOT of changes from 8.2 - 9.x, so I thought that I would upgrade to 8.3 first, fix any weirdness, and then upgrade to 9.x.

Comment: I see.  I would guess that an answer to your question will be forthcoming if a forum participant (familiar with org-mode) either has 8.3 installed, or is willing to install it for the specific purpose of helping you debug it.

Comment: Ty @lawlist. Yes I fear that I'll need to upgrade to the latest stable and fix everything that breaks at once.

Comment: @lawlist, thank you for the suggestion. Upgrading to 9.1 was actually much easier than I thought and I'm having the same issue there.